# Windows form freezes when try to call two functionalities

Tags: .net, visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I am working on some image processing stuffs using OpenCV, in visual Studio IDE (VC++).
What I am doing is displaying a webcam output in the windows form application using a picture pox and in the mean time I want to call an algorithm which uses the same camera for image processing stuff. The form application freezes when I am trying to perform both works together.And note that I am using threads to call the algorithm implemented in a seperate class.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

THis is how I am using the threads within the button click event
`$`
HANDLE h = CreateThread( NULL, 0, &(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Project::Form1::BGS(), this, 0, NULL );

void BGS()
{
//calling the algorithm inside this method.
}
`$`

Comment: Difficult to say anything if you don't explain and show how you are using the threads! Post some code please.

Comment: The code compiles without any issues and can perform these two funtions(display webcam and calling algorithm)seperatly but the problem arise when try to call both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have sort out this problem I used background workers for this.and This works perfectly.And for those who are intrested in displaying the vedio in windows form application using openCV and need to use the same vedio stream for other processings use the same instance of (CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0)) "capture" to perform both the actions.hope this will help to an extend.